# I want to switch to a new activity every time a tap any of the cards (Card View and RecyclerView)

Tags: android

I want to switch to a new activity every time a tap any of the cards (Card View and RecyclerView)
iam use source code from http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/#disqus_thread
   [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h44kI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simply attach corresponding on click listener to each cardview

```
cardView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Context c = v.getContext();
        c.startActivity(new Intent(c, CorrespondingActivity.class));
    }
}
```